# How to write 'x is not converging to 0'?

Tags: support, mathjax

To write 'x converges to 0' I can use `x\to 0` that produces $x\to 0$. But how do I write "x does not converge to 0'? I need to strike out $\to$. Well cancel package will be ok.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what strike you want.. Something like this $\require{cancel} \cancel \rightarrow$ works?

Comment: thanks @Zacky......

Comment: @Zacky post yours, it's more complete, I'll delete mine

Comment: @Magic_Isa You posted first, so I think you should keep it.

Comment: @Zacky see? OP wants the 'cancel package' answer

Comment: Hey, I needed both. I had to see which one looked better than the other.

Comment: By the way, what is OP? I saw that on several occasions.

Comment: "OP" in forums stands for "original poster", see [here](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Op).

Comment: well how did you correct my question? i mean how did you write codes with grey background. @Zacky

Comment: If you are using a computer then you can simply select a text and use Ctrl + K, otherwise from phone one option is to search for a text already with this grey background and copy  the quotes around it, e.g. \`text\` is  `text`.

Comment: ok @Zacky......

Answer (score 2):

The **cancel** package provides some ways to strike through. See [here](https://jansoehlke.com/2010/06/strikethrough-in-latex/) for more, but basically `\require{cancel} \cancel \to` produces: $\require{cancel} \cancel \to$.
However `\not \rightarrow` produces something smaller, like: $\not \to$.

Comment: looks good. thanks once again @Zacky

Comment: Or  `x\not\to 0` which displays $x\not\to 0$

Comment: @Magic_Isa this is what i was actually looking for.  smaller code but correct. thanks a lot.